# Power BI-BigQuery join error: "cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields"

Tags: join, powerbi, m, google-bigquery

I am creating a new table in Power BI based on direct query joins from BigQuery tables.

In the power query M language everything is correct syntax-wise and also the table looks fine when running the script.

However, when I want to display a visual of a column of that newly created table, I receive the following (Big Query/SQL) error:

"Full outer join (or "left outer join") cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join."

When I use inner join instead, there is no issue displaying a count of the metric.

This is the M code I am using:

`JoinTables1 = Table.Join(Tickets, "nID", Customer, "CustomerNumber", JoinKind.Inner),`

`JoinTables2 = Table.Join(JoinTables1, "CustomerKey", Screening, "ScreeningCustomerKey", JoinKind.LeftOuter)`

As a visual want to display the count of another metric, the screening sequence number, coming from the Screening table - however, then I get the error message described above.

Many thanks,

Janine

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @philipxy my question is why I am getting this error message.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Inner & outer join are ON a condition. Some DBMSs--although not yours according to the manual--allow JOIN without ON to mean inner join ON 1=1 which is cross join as is any outer join ON 1=1. You want to use outer join without ON--it's not in your manual, so what do you mean by it & why do you think it means that? You would see this if you re-read the manual for the functionality you want to use, which you should always do. If you don't tell us, how do we know? Also what did you learn googling the error message? [ask] [help]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. PS Show what layer is getting bad input & giving the error--BI or SQL/bigquery.